# Mac OS X - Location of socket for PHP & fastcgi?

Tags: php, fastcgi

I'm running on Mac OS X 10.5.6. I've built PHP 5.2.9 at /usr/local/php and enabled fast_cgi. I'm also using lighttpd as my server. I am confused as where the php fastcgi socket exists. My lighttpd server settings are:

```
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" =>
    ( "localhost" =>
        (
            "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi.socket",
            "bin-path" => "/usr/local/php/bin/php-cgi"
        )
    )
)
```

Its the "socket" => "/var/run/lighttpd/php-fastcgi.socket" that I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OS X usually the sockets are under

```
/private/var/run/
```

but it might be different in your case.
To be sure again, open Terminal and try

```
php -i
```

it should tell you

Comment: This is my info:
PHP Version => 5.2.9
Configure Command =>  './configure'  '--prefix=/usr/local/php' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/conf/php' '--enable-fastcgi'
Server API => Command Line Interface

Answer (score 0):

Check your PHP info—I would assume that the location of the socket would be listed in there.

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```